# При выделении текста в мобильном браузере Chrome не работает моё контекстное меню

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, события

Сделал, чтобы при выделении текста появлялось рядом контекстное меню, как на сайте Medium, только под другие задачи. На компе работает, а в мобильном браузере Chrome при выделении текста тут же срабатывает его родной функционал - сверху значки поделиться, скопировать,  найти....А моё меню не возникает. Уж пробовал и preventDefault и false при событиях touch ставить. MDN не помог. Как сделать, чтобы моё контекстное меню заработало в мобильном браузере?

Comment: Гм... а оно вообще там хоть где-то, на каком-то сайте, работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте что-то вроде этого

```js
//для мобилок
window.addEventListener("touchend", selectFunc);
//для компа
window.addEventListener("mouseup", selectFunc);

function selectFunc(e) {
  let selectedText = "";

  if (window.getSelection) {
    selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  if (selectedText.length > 0)
    console.log("выделен текст: " + selectedText)
}
```

```html
Тут текст который нужно выбрать
```

Comment: Забавно, но подставив для принудительного вызова функцию showMenu() после вашего console.log, (которая итак как бы должна была срабатывать и спокойно себе срабатывает в браузере компьютера) и при легкой прокрутке экрана, плавном касании(не клике) контекстное меню появляется!!! Правда родная браузерная приблуда сверху так и не исчезает, но уже нечто интересное.